Any Nash Equilibrium is a Correlated Equilibrium
I have a purely mathematical question regarding the proof that every Nash equilibrium is a correlated equilibrium. I've seen lots of intuition for this answer and related answers, but I've never seen it rigorously expressed.
Formally: Define a game $(N, A, u)$ as the following: A set of players $N = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$, where each player has a finite, non-empty action set $A_j$, and utility $u_j: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is defined as the cartesian product of all action sets. Define a strategy as a distribution over possible actions, such that $s_j: A_j \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+, \sum s_j(a_j) = 1$, and the set of all possible distributions as $S_j$, again with $S$ as their cartesian product. Define expected utility as $v_j: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$: $$v_j(s_j, s_{-j}) = \sum_{\mathbf{a} \in A} u_j(\mathbf{a})p(\mathbf{a})$$
where $s_{-j}$ denotes the strategies of players not $j$, and $p(\mathbf{a})$ denotes the product of individual strategies $s_i(a_i)$ (Assuming independence here). We define a Nash equilibrium: $$\mathbf{s}^* \in S \: \:\text{if} \: \: \forall j \in N,  \forall s_j \in S_j, \:v_j(s_j^*, s_{-j}^*) \geq v_j(s_j, s_{-j}^*)$$
Now, consider correlated equilibria. Define $\pi$ as a distribution over all action profiles, $\pi: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+, \sum_A \pi(\mathbf{a}) = 1$. Let $\pi$ be called a "correlated equilibrium" if: $$\forall a_j' \in A_j, \sum_{a_{-j} \in A_{-j}} \pi(a_j, a_{-j})\Big[ u_j(a_j, a_{-j}) - u_j(a_j', a_{-j})\Big] \geq 0$$
Now finally, to the proof. Show $\pi(\mathbf{a}) = p(\mathbf{a}^*) = \prod_{i=1}^Ns_i^*(a_i)$ is a correlated equilibrium (Satisfies the equilibrium above), when $\mathbf{s}^*$ is Nash. The proof I saw relies on the following critical fact:
$$\forall a_j \in \operatorname{supp}(s_j^*), \forall a_j' \in A_j, \sum_{a_{-j} \in A_{-j}}u_j(a_j, a_{-j})\prod_{i \neq j} s_i^*(a_i) \geq \sum_{a_{-j} \in A_{-j}}u_j(a_j', a_{-j})\prod_{i\neq j}s_i^*(a_i)$$
How do we get this? I've tried to get here from the Nash definition, but I can't explicitly get to showing that these pure strategies are weakly preferred. Reference: "A Course in Game Theory" by Osborne and Rubinstein. Thanks.
